# SonarQube - Coverage measure shows two different results

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, measure

Does anyone know whether this is a bug or is there any reason? Please, see the picture below

[image: project homepage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug.

The coverage on top is the Line Coverage while the one below is the Overall Coverage